# Spark saveAsTextFile() results in Mkdirs failed to create for half of the directory

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently running a Java Spark Application in tomcat and receiving the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/opt/folder/tmp/file.json/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201603031703_0001_m_000000_5
```

on the line

`text.saveAsTextFile("/opt/folder/tmp/file.json") //where text is a JavaRDD<String>`

The issue is that /opt/folder/tmp/ already exists and successfully creates up to /opt/folder/tmp/file.json/_temporary/0/ and then it runs into what looks like a permission issue with the remaining part of the path `_temporary/attempt_201603031703_0001_m_000000_5` itself, but I gave the tomcat user permissions (`chown -R tomcat:tomcat tmp/` and `chmod -R 755 tmp/`) to the tmp/ directory. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks

Edit for @javadba:

```
[root@ip tmp]# ls -lrta 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 4 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  3 16:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 file.json
drwxrwxrwx 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 .

[root@ip tmp]# cd file.json/
[root@ip file.json]# ls -lrta 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 _temporary
drwxrwxrwx 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 .

[root@ip file.json]# cd _temporary/
[root@ip _temporary]# ls -lrta 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 .

[root@ip _temporary]# cd 0/
[root@ip 0]# ls -lrta 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar  7 20:01 .
```

The exception in catalina.out

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/opt/folder/tmp/file.json/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201603072001_0001_m_000000_5
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: can you post how you submit your application? what master? and do you use speculation by any chance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`saveAsTextFile` is really processed by Spark executors. Depending on your Spark setup, Spark executors may run as a *different user* than your Spark application driver. I guess the spark application driver prepares the directory for the job fine, but then the executors running as a different user have no rights to write in that directory.

Changing to 777 won't help, because permissions are not inherited by child dirs, so you'd get 755 anyways.

Try running your Spark application as the same user that runs your Spark.

Comment: Most probable response. I just set up my application to use HDFS/S3 as a work around. Did not run into the issues with permissions, if I get the chance Ill backtrack and confirm this.

Comment: how do you run the spark executors under the same user?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to try changing to `777` temporarily .  See if it works at that point. There have been bugs/issues wrt  permissions on local file system.  If that still does not work let us know if anything changed or precisely same result.

Comment: Tried that as well before the 755 the result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: please show us output of `ls -lrta /opt/folder/tmp/file.json/_temporary/0/_temporary`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Added the update. Thats as far as it goes. It cannot mkdir past `0/` it would seem

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, and my issue has been resolved by using full HDFS path:

**Error**

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/QA/Gajendra/SparkAutomation/Source/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180616221100_0002_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/gajendra/LiClipse Workspace/SpakAggAutomation)

**Solution**

Use full HDFS path with `hdfs://localhost:54310/<filePath>`

> hdfs://localhost:54310/QA/Gajendra/SparkAutomation

Answer (score 1):

Could it be `selinux/apparmor` that plays you a trick? Check with `ls -Z` and system logs.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the full path works for me.
Example:

```
 file:/Users/yourname/Documents/electric-chargepoint-2017-data
```

Comment: This works, but the path has to be a path that does not exist yet or an exception will be thrown. I got around this by using a timestamp to name the folder.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been experiencing the same issue, with my setup there is no HDFS and Spark is running in stand-alone mode. I haven't been able to save spark dataframes to an NFS share using the native Spark methods. The process runs as a local user, and I try to write to the users home folder. Even when creating a subfolder with 777 I cannot write to the folder.

The workaround for this is to convert the dataframe with `toPandas()` and after that `to_csv()`. This magically works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as yours.

I also did not want to write to hdfs but to a local memory share.

After some research, I found that for my case the reason is: there are several nodes executing, however,  some of the nodes has no access to the directory where you want to write your data.

Thus the solution is to make the directory available to all nodes, and then it works~

Comment: how do you do that

Answer (score 0):

We need to run the application in local mode.

```
 val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .appName("applicationName")
      .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the transformed data fits into master node memory, convert pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe and then save the pandas dataframe to file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for small files can be to convert the pyspark dataframe into a `Pandas` dataframe and then export it as a csv `df.toPandas.to_csv(myDf.csv)`, but this is not feasible because of memory limitations and performance overhead of pandas dataframes.

Answer (score -1):

this is tricky one, but simple to solve. One must configure job.local.dir variable to point to working directory. Following code works fine with writing CSV file:

```
def xmlConvert(spark):
    etl_time = time.time()
    df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='HistoricalTextData').load(
        '/home/zangetsu/proj/prometheus-core/demo/demo-1-iot-predictive-maintainance/dataset/train/')
    df = df.withColumn("TimeStamp", df["TimeStamp"].cast("timestamp")).groupBy("TimeStamp").pivot("TagName").sum(
        "TagValue").na.fill(0)
    df.repartition(1).write.csv(
        path="/home/zangetsu/proj/prometheus-core/demo/demo-1-iot-predictive-maintainance/result/",
        mode="overwrite",
        header=True,
        sep=",")
    print("Time taken to do xml transformation: --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - etl_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('XML ETL') \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config('job.local.dir', '/home/zangetsu/proj/prometheus-core/demo/demo-1-iot-predictive-maintainance') \
        .config('spark.driver.memory','64g') \
        .config('spark.debug.maxToStringFields','200') \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0') \
        .getOrCreate()

    print('Session created')

    try:
        xmlConvert(spark)

    finally:
        spark.stop()
```